# How to properly register dynamically created modeded in admin pannel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating my models using the `create_model` that is proposed in [documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) and here is how I call this function to create multiple model with different names:

```
def create_servers(server_names_path):
    with open(server_names_path) as f:
        server_names = json.load(f)

    def set_file_names(cls, args):
        cls.file_names = json.dumps(args)

    def get_file_names(cls):
        return json.loads(cls.file_names)

    for name in server_names:
        model_class = create_model(name,
                                   fields={'path': models.CharField(max_length=200),
                                           'file_names': models.TextField(),
                                           'set_file_names': set_file_names,
                                           'get_file_names': get_file_names,
                                           '__str__': lambda self: self.__name__},
                                   app_label='SearchEngine',
                                   module='SearchEngine.models',
                                   options=None,
                                   admin_opts={})
        # with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        #    editor.create_model(model_class)
    call_command('makemigrations')
    call_command('migrate')
    reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
    clear_url_caches()
```

As you can see I'm passing an empty dictionary as the `admin_opts` so that in `ceate_model` the registration gets executed.

Now, my problem is that after running the code it creates the migrations in `migrations` directory but the new models don't appear in `admin` panel.

I also ran the code multiple times by unquoting the quoted lines and/or running the `reload` before and after the migrations.

The weired thing is that after this it creates the modes but doesn't show them in `admin` panel and when I run the `makemigrations` and then `migrate` commands in terminal it removes my dynamic models.

Comment: Are you just trying to register every model in your models page with the admin panel??

Comment: @Joe Yes that's what I'm goring to do, but since my modes are defined dynamically, the `admin` module is not able to register them properly (they're not ready in a module to be called at the time of registration).

Comment: @Mat can you please post the error you got when you want to register the model?  What Django version are you using?

Comment: @hansTheFranz Sorry, I realized that this is not a way that I should go at all and I juts dropped using it.

Comment: dropped using Django or the project? Anyway good luck.

Comment: @hansTheFranz Going this way, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use this to automate model registration. I'm not sure if it will work for your situation with the dynamic model registration but I would imagine it is just a simple change to accomplish that.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from . import models as appmodels


for name, var in appmodels.__dict__.items():
    if type(var) is ModelBase:
        admin.site.register(var)
```